# Why isn 't Object.class a catch all?

Tags: java

I was writing an application where I had to use foo.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new FooRenderer()). When the program was running it did not do what I expected. Namely only Strings were getting colored correctly while Integers, Shorts etc did not get colored correctly. I had assumed that using Object.class would have worked for all types. Why was it necessary to use Short.class and Integer.class in order for the Render to work correctly?

Edit 1: below is the code that was requested. The application itself now works because I put in the below four lines but I'd like to understand why Object.class wouldn't catch all of the possible types.

```
foo.setDefaultRenderer(Integer.class, new FooRenderer());
foo.setDefaultRenderer(Short.class,new FooRenderer());
foo.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new FooRenderer());
foo.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new FooRenderer());
```

Comment: suppose you share the code you have tried in order to propose a solution.

Comment: @RajithPemabandu see edit

Comment: What is `foo`? A `JTable`? The answer will depend on the implementation of whatever `setDefaultRenderer` is doing.

Comment: yes its a jtable sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such questions, always first look at the source code, for example: [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/).

```
public void setDefaultEditor(Class<?> columnClass, TableCellEditor editor) {
    if (editor != null) {
        defaultEditorsByColumnClass.put(columnClass, editor);
    }
    else {
        defaultEditorsByColumnClass.remove(columnClass);
    }
}
```

If you do this, you'll see that the JTable uses a HashTable called defaultEditorsByColumnClass to hold these renderers

```
transient protected Hashtable defaultEditorsByColumnClass;
```

> A table of objects that display and edit the contents of a cell, indexed by class as declared in getColumnClass in the TableModel interface.

and that the class type is the key to this table. Since Object is a different type from Short, from String,... the behavior that you're seeing makes complete sense because in this situation the Map's `Class<?>` key would be neither covariant nor contravariant but rather would be *invariant*.